# extracting leaf after watershed segmentation in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation, watershed

after I applied watershed segmentation, I want to extract remained leaf from image,and only I want to get without background like image-2. Please can you help me. Thanks a lot. I attach below also my code.
I'm new at stackoverflow, therefore I'm not allowed to post images.I asked the same qustion in mathworks, you can check the images from there if you will.

Thanks a lot in advance.

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/237106-extracting-leaf-from-background

image-1: after watershed segmentation(colored version):

image-2:image to be ;

my code:

```
% I -- intensity image
  % Gmag -- gradient mag.
      se = strel('disk', 30);
Ie = imerode(I, se);
Iobr = imreconstruct(Ie, I);
figure
imshow(Iobr), title('Opening-by-reconstruction (Iobr)')
Iobrd = imdilate(Iobr, se);
Iobrcbr = imreconstruct(imcomplement(Iobrd), imcomplement(Iobr));
Iobrcbr = imcomplement(Iobrcbr);
figure
imshow(Iobrcbr), title('Opening-closing by reconstruction (Iobrcbr)')
fgm = imregionalmax(Iobrcbr);
figure
imshow(fgm), title('Regional maxima of opening-closing by reconstruction (fgm)')
% modify area 
I2 = I;
I2(fgm) = 255;
figure
imshow(I2), title('Regional maxima superimposed on original image (I2)')
se2 = strel(ones(10,10));
fgm2 = imclose(fgm, se2);
fgm3 = imerode(fgm2, se2);
fgm4 = bwareaopen(fgm3, 100);
I3 = I;
I3(fgm4) = 255;
figure
imshow(I3)
title('Modified regional maxima superimposed on original image (fgm4)')
% background markers
bw = im2bw(Iobrcbr, graythresh(Iobrcbr));
figure
imshow(bw), title('Thresholded opening-closing by reconstruction (bw)')
D = bwdist(bw);
DL = watershed(D);
bgm = DL == 0;
figure
imshow(bgm), title('Watershed ridge lines (bgm)')
gradmag2 = imimposemin(Gmag, bgm | fgm4);
L = watershed(gradmag2);
I4 = I;
I4(imdilate(L == 0, ones(3, 3)) | bgm | fgm4) = 255;
figure
imshow(I4)
title('Markers and object boundaries superimposed on original image (I4)')
Lrgb = label2rgb(L, 'jet', 'w', 'shuffle');
figure
imshow(Lrgb)
title('Colored watershed label matrix (Lrgb)')
figure
imshow(I)
hold on
himage = imshow(Lrgb);
himage.AlphaData = 0.3;
title('Lrgb superimposed transparently on original image')


props = regionprops(L);
[~,ind] = max([props.Area]);
imshow(L == ind);
```

Comment: ... so what exactly is your question?  I don't understand what you want exactly.

Comment: After I apply watershed, I'm having L matrix (which is segmented regionally). ThenI want to extract target leaf which you see in the first image, largest one. Next, I want to have an image only with the target leaf and black background like image-2. As you see, image-2 has only the leaf which is aimed to extracted. I hope I explained better.

Comment: Can you upload the original image? Are you set on using watershed? There are better algorithms for doing this  IMHO

Comment: am not allowed for image upload for now, but you can dowload from below link. Second, Grabcut is actually better than this watershed segmentation, but it needs interaction, I need to do it automatically and in matlab. If you suggest me any other algorithms I would be appreciated. For image: (http://i.imgur.com/OUXuZj5.jpg)

Comment: Yeah. Where's the link?

Comment: I already added above.

Answer (score 0):

- It's not possible to extract the leaf according to the segmented image, because the yellow component cuts the leaf in different parts.
- Moreover, according to the source code, I understand that you use a basic watershed that produces an over segmentation. Use a watershed constrained, also known as watershed with markers.
- Find a way to share the original image and the image after processing.

Comment: No, I use the marker watershed, not basic one. Is there any suggestion to solve oversegmentation problem? Also, even you solve this problem, how can I extract image like 2nd image?

Comment: Also, here is the link for orjinal image:

Comment: Your result shows many zones, which means that you use many inner markers. As you want only one leaf, you need to use only one inner marker (and as many outer markers you want). Then, you will have only one zone.

Comment: I reduce the number of leaf markers to one, but result did not change, on the target leaf still many areas exist.

Comment: is it possible to share the code what you mean exactly please, thanks

Comment: I don't use Matlab. In the constrained/markers watershed, you have as many zones as markers. Therefore, if you have only one inner and one outer marker, you must have two zones into your results. In the watershed you use, you seem to give only one image.

Answer (score 0):

I confirm that you certainly have an issue with the watershed you use. I ran your code on my own library, and I used: one inner marker (biggest component, consequently the leaf on the corner is discarded), one outer (dilation of the inner), the gradient image.

And here is my result: www.thibault.biz/StackOverflow/ResultLeaf.png. So only one component, because I use only one inner marker. It's not perfect, but already closer and easier to post-process.